# inquiry -surface Chebyshev

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I am working in grasshopper and need a formula that can divide any surface into equal points.
I need an algorithm that can give me equidistributed points on the surface Chebyshev

Comment: What is surface Chebyshev? can you define it of give a link? How a surface can be divided by points? How many points? Please elaborate a little more on your question

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: It seems like programming question if you need a formula to 3D program. Otherwise it is not easy to follow your question, there is no standard surface madr by Chebyshev, mayhap polynomials used as basis, but in that case what do you mean by equal points?